# Qooxdoo and JS-Ctypes generating source

Tags: qooxdoo, jsctypes

I am using `JS-Ctypes` in my `Qooxdoo` project.
When I try to generate source, I am given the following error:

> Scanning libraries -Unknown operator u'import

This error is risen when using the following function:

`Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");`

Does any one know how to make qooxdoo recognize js-ctypes and this operator?

Answer (score 1):

It's the use of of the word `import`. It's a "future reserved word" per ECMA spec, and you should not use those (Identifiers are not allowed to match reserved words). This is why the generator exits. The solution is simply to chose another identifier for this method, e.g. `import_` suffices.

But the error message is bad, to say the least. If you want to help, open a [bug report](http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/) for this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Thomas, but I was getting the error TypeError: Components.utils.import_ is not a function. Using ["import"] solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is :

Components.utils["import"];

For more information follow this link:
http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/Qooxdoo-and-JS-Ctypes-problem-while-generating-source-tc7580977.html